# asp.net mvc razor application - Select data from database within range

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a quick SQL question. 
In my MVC Razor application, I have two text input asking for start and end values.

These values will be numbers, they correspond to Version
Ex:  4.0.100 - 4.0.157

So i would need to display all the version between 100 - 157
I have direct access tot he database, and it's version column

My question is: How do i write or get a query to display this?

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BenchmarkApp.Models
{
public partial class Build
{
    public Build()
    {
        this.Executions = new List<Execution>();
    }

    public string Version { get; set; }
    public bool Obfuscated { get; set; }
    public bool Release { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsX64 { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Execution> Executions { get; set; }
}
```

}

The view .cshtml showing the two inputs:

```
<td> 
                            Viewing Option: @Html.DropDownList("ViewOption", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ViewSelect, new { @onchange = "submit()" })
                     </td>          
                     <td>
                            @if (ViewBag.RangeVisible == true)
                            {   
                                @Html.Label("Range: ");
                                @Html.TextBox("start", "Start", new { maxlength = 10, size = 10 });
                                @Html.TextBox("end", "End", new { maxlength = 10, size = 10, @onchange = "submit()" });
                            }
```

Controller class where i access the text inputs:

```
        string start = form["start"];
        string end = form["end"];
        string custom = form["customRange"];


        string viewSelect = form["ViewOption"];

        if (viewSelect.Equals("range"))
        {
            ViewBag.RangeVisible = true;

        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well you can do either linq to sql, a stored procedure, or just write the sql out on the page. Linq is probably the easiest if you dont know much sql.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: im using the Build Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use the [`Version.TryParse`-Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.version.tryparse.aspx) to convert your version strings into `Version` objects. First, you might write an extension method to perform the parsing of the string/int values to compareable `Version` objects:

```
public static Version ParseToVersion(this string input)
{
    Version result = null;
    Version.TryParse(input, out result);
    return result;
}
```

Then you can easily use linq and select the range you want by using the extension method above:

```
public IEnumerable<Build> GetBuildsInRange(string beginVersion, string lastVersion)
{
    var startVersion = start.ParseToVersion();
    var endVersion = end.ParseToVersion();
    if (startVersion == null || endVersion == null) return IEnumerable.Empty<Build>();
    return YourDbContext.Builds.Where(b =>
        b.Version.ParseToVersion() >= startVersion
     && b.Version.ParseToVersion() <= endVersion);
}
```

**Note:** You might verify that `b.Version.ParseToVersion()`, `startVersion` and `endVersion` are not null!

Due to you're using Razor I guess you have a method in your Controller returning the ActionResult (final view). Just feed this view with the information returned by the GetBuildsInRange method.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! and I'm sorry for the late response. I'm fairly new to ASP.net development, can you explain a bit more in detail what it is i have to do? and perhaps explain at the same time! thank you much appreciated!

Comment: @StephenSugumar Take a look now.